# how to use containment attribute without jquery-ui plug-in

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, containment

I am done with drag event without jquery-ui. And then I have to make the area elements just can be moved. It is like a containment attribute in jquery-ui. how to make the confined area.

```
(function ($) {
var elPosStartCounsel = 0;
var elPosCurrentCounsel = 0;
var elPosStartX = 0;
var elPosCurrentX = 0;

$.fn.drags = function (opt) {

    opt = $.extend({
        handle: "",
        cursor: "pointer",
    }, opt);

    if (opt.handle === "") {
        var $el = this;
    } else {
        var $el = this.find(opt.handle);
    }

    return $el.css('cursor', opt.cursor).on("mousedown", function (e) {
        elPosStartCounsel = $(this).offset().top + $(this).offset().left;
        elPosStartX = $(this).offset().top + $(this).offset().left;
        if (opt.handle === "") {
            var $drag = $(this).addClass('draggable');
        } else {
            var $drag = $(this).addClass('active-handle').parent().addClass('draggable');
        }
        var z_idx = $drag.css('z-index'),
            drg_h = $drag.outerHeight(),
            drg_w = $drag.outerWidth(),
            pos_y = $drag.offset().top + drg_h - e.pageY,
            pos_x = $drag.offset().left + drg_w - e.pageX;
        $drag.css('z-index', 1000).parents().on("mousemove", function (e) {
            $('.draggable').offset({
                top: e.pageY + pos_y - drg_h,
                left: e.pageX + pos_x - drg_w
            }).on("mouseup", function () {
                elPosCurrentCounsel = $(this).offset().top + $(this).offset().left;
                elPosCurrentX = $(this).offset().top + $(this).offset().left;
                $(this).removeClass('draggable').css('z-index', z_idx);
            });
        });
        e.preventDefault(); // disable selection
    }).on("mouseup", function (e) {
        elPosCurrentCounsel = $(this).offset().top + $(this).offset().left;
        elPosCurrentX = $(this).offset().top + $(this).offset().left;

        if (opt.handle === "") {
            $(this).removeClass('draggable');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('active-handle').parent().removeClass('draggable');
        }
    })
}

$('#linktalk').drags();
$('.counsel_btn').drags();
```

this is my source.

Comment: post whatever you have done so far

Comment: @AnanthaRajuC I comment the source, Thanks.

Comment: To create containment is no easy task. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, why are you avoiding `draggable()`?